# Stack of blocks in Prolog

Tags: variables, prolog, block, predicate

I'm trying to do something very simple in Prolog, but for some reason it's not working and I can't figure out why. I'm using SWI.

I have a bunch of blocks, labeled a to f, and they're all stacked on top of each other, a being at the bottom and f all the way on top. Like this:

```
on(b, a).
on(c, b).
on(d, c).
on(e, d).
on(f, e).
above(X, Y) :- on(X, Y).
above(X, Y) :- on(X, Z), above(Z, Y).
```

So one block is above another block if there's some block beneath it that is on top of that block. Makes sense to me.

So now I want to define a predicate that tells me if a certain block has exactly 3 blocks beneath it. In my example that would be block d. So I started with:

```
exactlyThree(X) :- above(X, Y), above(Y, Z), above (Z, W), \+ above(W, _).
```

So X has exaclty three blocks beneath it if X is above a block Y, if Y is above a block Z, if Z is above a block W and block W is not above any block.
But that's not working.

So I tried this, which is practically the same thing:

```
bottomBlock(X) :- \+ above(X, _).
exactlyThree(X) :- above(X, Y), above(Y, Z), above (Z, W), bottomBlock(W).
```

That didn't work either. As a test it tried:

```
?-bottomBlock(a).
true.
```

Makes sense, but then I tried:

```
?-bottomBlock(X).
false.
```

What's going on here? Why doesn't prolog say X=a? And why aren't my predicates doing what they're supposed to?

Comment: One problem is that your definition of `exactlyThree` is using `above` which allows an arbitrary number of blocks in between it's arguments, not exactly one. If you want *exactly* three, you need to be calling `on` from `exactlyThree`, not `above`. So if you wrote, `exactlyThree(X) :- on(X, Y), on(Y, Z), on(Z, W), \+ on(W, _).` you'd get `X = d`.

Comment: The reason the `bottomBlock(X)` call doesn't generate `X = a` is because the expression `\+ above(X, _).` can't "generate" an `X` that makes `above(X, _)` false. One way around this is to define your predicate as: `bottomBlock(X) :- is_block(X), \+ above(X, _).` and define `is_block(X)` to be true if `X` is a valid block. Then the predicate will know what the "universe of valid block" is to decide on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the bottom (hehe):

> ```
> ?-bottomBlock(X).
> false.
> ```
>
> Why doesn't prolog say X=a?

Because it won't invent things to match a variable. You need to assert *something*, not just negate.

```
bottomBlock(X) :- on(_, X), \+ above(X, _).
```

> ```
> exactlyThree(X) :- above(X, Y), above(Y, Z), above (Z, W), \+ above(W, _).
> ```

This should match 3 blocks or more: if X is above Y, it could be 10 blocks above. You need to use `on` in order to guarantee it is exactly 3 blocks away.